# How is the Default UITableView Scrolling Supposed to Work when Items are Deleted and Inserted Programatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` with two sections. Items can move from one section to another, as seen in the image below.

[image]

The basic interaction is as follows:

- you swipe a cell/row
- that cell is removed from its section
- that cell is added to the bottom of the other section

**Note**, I'm using a sequence of `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` with `CATransaction`s. Remove followed by add isn't the only table operation in place; for the general approach I want chained `insert`/`delete`/`update` animations to start when the preceding operation has finished. Here's an example:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    [table beginUpdates];
    // update data source...
    // insertRows...
    [table endUpdates];
}];

[table beginUpdates];
// update data source...
// deleteRows...
[table endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```

When there are enough items in the table view to take up more than a screen's worth of space, (what I think is) the default `UITableView` scrolling kicks in when cells are removed from one section and added to another.

My assumption (as I haven't found any reference to scroll behaviour in the docs) is that the `UITableView` scrolls to place/keep the inserted row in view.

Consider the example of swiping a cell to remove it from one section and have it added to the other:

- the cell is currently in view because the user is swiping it (so perhaps there is no change/scroll required for the `deleteRows...`
- (in some circumstances) the table view scrolls for the subsequent `insertRows...`; the scroll happens before the insert so that the animated insert is observed

For example, in the image below, swipe one of the cells in the bottom section, table view scrolls, then inserts at the bottom of the top section...

[image]

I say *some circumstances* because this behaviour is observed if the insert takes place in the top section (section 0). When the delete / insert is from section 0 to section 1, the table view does not scroll at all.

I'm also seeing some other behaviour I don't understand. In the case where some of the cells have more than one line of text (cells aren't all the same size) - the scroll seems to "not work". At first the scroll amount simply appeared *wrong*; however, testing with all the cells being single line revealed consistent scrolling when the insert occurred in section 0.

The following image shows the *wrong* scrolling:

[image]

I have two *specific* questions and one *general* question.

**Specific question #1**: is there a hierarchy for `UITableView`s such that section 0 is *preferred*, so the table view will scroll to section 0 so that inserts are observed, but not scroll to other sections?

**Specific question #2**: is it the height of the cells in the above example that is causing the *wrong* scrolling to be observed?

This is the code I'm using for calculating the height of the table view cells:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger index = indexPath.row;
    ParsedItem* item;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        item = [_parsedItemList.toDoList objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    else {
        item = [_parsedItemList.doneList objectAtIndex:index];
    }

    NSAttributedString* attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:item.displayText attributes:_tableViewTextAttrNormal];

    CGFloat height = [self textViewHeightForAttributedText:attrString andWidth:300.00];
    return fmaxf(50.0, height);
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50.0;
}

- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString*)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width {
    UITextView* calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [calculationView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```

**General question**: as I mentioned above, I haven't found anything in the docs that describes how the scrolling is supposed to work. Is there a general rule or principal that I've missed? I don't want to add explicit scroll operations if I'm simply *doing it wrong*...